# Change the voice?

Tags: passive-voice

What will be the passive voice of the below sentence? And is that sentence is active voice?

Sentence: "I knew her well"

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the sentence is in the active voice.

The passive voice of the sentence is:

> She was well known to me.

Comment: Interesting. The usual by-phrase has to be a to-phrase.

Comment: "By" would be acceptable instead of "to".